# About the sequence of the MessageBox in Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, message-queue

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread td = new Thread(threadRun);
        td.Start();

        **MessageBox.Show("abc");**  //This is the key
        Thread.Sleep(8000);
    }
    private void ChangeText()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("changeText");
    }

    private void threadRun()
    {
        MethodInvoker In = new MethodInvoker(ChangeText);

        this.Invoke(In);
    }
```

what happen in this code is:

> changeText messageBox show up,
>
> abc messageBox show up,
>
> the UI freezes for 8 seconds

BUT if I delete the abc MessageBox, the behavior is:

> the UI freezes for 8 seconds
>
> changeText messageBox show up

In VS's debug mode, I can clearly note that abc execute before changeText, but the pop sequence is opposite.

If the abcMessageBox alters to new Form().ShowDialog() it acts the same way.
obviously modal dialog changes the sequence, but, WHY?

Before this experiment, I thought that Invoke means we enqueue a packed Delegate  to the inner queue of the UI thread, and The UI thread will execute the delegate after button1_click is finished, which also just dequeued from the inner queue, make it thread-safe. This seems make sence if the abc doesn't exist.

what's happening inside?
according to the sourceCode of Messagebox, it simply calls the win32API from the thread rather than sending some message or wrapping some delegate.

Sorry my windows programming is not got and thanks for your help

Comment: MessageBox.Show("abc") will spin up a message loop which processes the invoke call from your background thread.

Comment: Never, never, never hang the UI thread with a Thread.Sleep() call.  It becomes incapable of doing anything useful, like responding to user input and handling Invoke() calls.  All that MessageBox does here is delaying the hang so the Invoke call can squeak in before it goes catatonic.  Technically there is no guarantee that it can squeak in soon enough, but you just can't hit the OK button quickly enough to observe that.

Comment: But how does Invoke work? Why it is able to insert inside a running function? As far as I'm concerned, the ui thread is running button1_Click method now and it should be atomic. This experiment is exaggrated. But in real case button1_click will not literally finish in a flash. It will still take a few time to do something, for instance, 500ms or 1 second, manipulate many controls. When will the Invoke take place? Is the order predictable?@Hans Passant

Comment: Right, the Click event handler normally executes in less than a microsecond.  After which it returns to the dispatcher loop that got started by Application.Run().  Ready to do other stuff, like executing the invoke delegate target.  When you make that event handler take 8 seconds then it becomes a lot more obvious that the invoke target does not in fact "insert inside a running function", the dispatcher loop handles one job at a time.  MessageBox is a dialog, it is special in running its own dispatcher loop, the same kind that Application.Run() uses, which prevents the UI from freezing.